# How to detect an application executed by a Process whether the application stops working due to an invalid input?

Tags: c#, pdflatex

I want to create a `LaTeX` editor to produce pdf documents.
Behind the scene, my application uses `pdflatex.exe` executed through a `Process` instance.

`pdflatex.exe` needs an input file, e.g., `input.tex` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX\ is my tool.
\end{document}
```

For the sake of simplicity, here is the minimal `c#` codes used in my `LaTeX` editor:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();

            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "input.tex";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";

            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }

        static void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // remove all auxiliary files, excluding *.pdf.
        }
    }
}
```

The question is

**How to detect the `pdflatex.exe` whether it stops working due to an invalid input?**

### Edit

This is the final working solution:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();

            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-interaction=nonstopmode input.tex";// Edit
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();

            //Edit
            if (p.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Succeeded...");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed...");
            }
        }

        static void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // remove all  files excluding *.pdf

            //Edit
            Console.WriteLine("exited...");
        }
    }
}
```

The idea using `-interaction=nonstopmode` belongs to @Martin [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12770/how-to-prevent-pdflatex-to-stop-working-due-to-an-invalid-input-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most command-line applications set an exit code to indicate success or failure.  You test it thus:

```
p.WaitForExit();
if (p.ExitCode == 0) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you can understand if `pdflatex` has stopped working by looking at its output (e.g. matching an error message, seeing that it doesn't output anything for more than 30 seconds, something like that).

To be able to perform such checks, you should redirect the standard output and standard error of `pdflatex` (you can find many examples just by [searching in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RedirectStandardOutput), the key is the `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` property) to a stream that you can read/a callback to a function of yours; in this way you should be able to detect the condition whence you deduce that `pdflatex` is stuck, and then you can kill it with `p.Kill()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a means to detect your process has stopped working, you can use

```
p.Kill();
```

to terminate the process

One way to go about it is a timeout. If you have a separate thread to launch this proces, you can start the thread and use

```
        if(processThread.Join(waitTime))
        {
            // worked
        }
        else
        {
            // Timeout. need to kill process
        }
```

where waitTime is of type `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0):

Time-outs are better suited for a shelled application that performs background processing. The following code sample sets a time-out for the shelled application. The time-out for the example is set to 5 seconds. You may want to adjust this number (which is calculated in milliseconds) for your testing:

```
//Set a time-out value.
int timeOut = 5000;
//Start the process.
Process p = Process.Start(someProcess);
//Wait for window to finish loading.
p.WaitForInputIdle();
//Wait for the process to exit or time out.
p.WaitForExit(timeOut);
//Check to see if the process is still running.
if (p.HasExited == false)
{
    //Process is still running.
    //Test to see if the process is hung up.
    if (p.Responding)
    {
        //Process was responding; close the main window.
        p.CloseMainWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        //Process was not responding; force the process to close.
        p.Kill();
    }
}
//continue
```

Comment: IIRC the `Responding` property makes sense only for GUI applications, since it checks if the application's main thread message pump is still processing messages (or something like that); being `pdflatex` a console application, this shouldn't apply here.

Comment: @user596314: I added an example for shell apps.